# I want to validate the ordertype and move on to menu option. But the ordertype loop is getting executed again and again

Tags: loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I want to validate the ordertype and move on to menu option. But the ordertype loop is getting executed again and again.I am not able to break the loop and get out of it. Please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int orderId;
    String name;
    String emailId;
    Long mobileNo;
    String orderType;
    String menu;
    
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Order ID :");
    orderId = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Name :");
    name = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Enter email ID :");
    emailId = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Mobile No :");
    mobileNo = scanner.nextLong();
    
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Order Type [snacks or meals ? ]");
        orderType = scanner.next();
        if (orderType== "snacks" || orderType=="meals" ) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter CorrectOrder Type [snacks or meals ? ]");
    }
        
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Menu [veg or non-veg or vegan ? ]");
        menu = scanner.next();
        if (menu== "veg" || menu=="non-veg" || menu=="vegan") {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter Correct menu option [veg or non-veg or vegan ? ]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get a better response to your question, always tag it with the appropriate language tag. Use the `Edit tags` link under your question to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct code.if (orderType.equals("snacks") || orderType.equals("meals")) will work in place of ==.